# Why does this JSONP request sometimes fail and sometimes not?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am trying to understand how to retrieve cross-site JSONP using jQuery 1.7.2, but it seems I don't get it. I use the following idiom:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp"
})
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  // handle data
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // error logging
})
.always(function () {
  // mandatory clean-up
});
```

[See also an executable jsFiddle of this idiom.](http://jsfiddle.net/kJkwx/5/)

When I use the code to read from http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/ everything works fine. However, when I try to read from a different source, e.g. http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=abc , the code fails. Even worse, it seems that the execution is stuck somewhere while doing the call. Neither done(), fail() or always() are executed, and I can't even learn what the problem is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me for twitter just fine. Maybe twitter limits the amount of JSON requests you can send it a day and you're over your quota?

Comment: Works fine here. Network tab also shows the script loading.

Comment: Wow, that's more than strange. I just switched to my laptop (and hence another network) and it worked. Then I started another browser on the first computer and it worked two. The problem seems to lie with my Firefox installation on the first computer, the same browser on a different pc works too. I am still confused, but thanks for the help.